# 404 on an existing file

Tags: html, web, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

Recently I was trying to run an completed website on a hosting of my client. On my hosting, wedos.net, everything works properly, so does when running on my localhost. But on this particuluar hosting (Forpsi.com), lot of things act strange. 
The thing that I found most annoying, is that server returns 404 Error on a files that exist - but only for *.svg, *.otf, *.woff files etc..

*.php, *.html, *.css,... Each one of these work properly. Not sure where is the issue.

According to this problem, my fonts won't load, neither do my svg files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the apache rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your host has a blacklist of extensions, you should ask them if they got any filters in [Apache Module mod_access](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html)
You can host these elsewhere  if you can't resolve it in this server